How to run PN532 with 6Pin FTDI FT232RL FT232 Module to connect to PC
I'm very noob with NFC and these stuff, I bought PN532 NFC RFID Wireless Module V3 (the small red one) and I bought 6Pin FTDI FT232RL FT232 Module For Arduino USB to TTL UART Serial Wire Adapter RS232 to use it on PC. I added the 4 pin side then connected the USB 6 pins to it, but no luck, nothing showed on PC. Because it's 6 pins and did not know which one will work so I tried to put the 4 pin 3 times to cover all 6 pins.
I installed Install ccid, libnfc, acsccid, pcsclite and pcsc-tools. I did pcsc_scan but all it showed was the USB cable not the module itself.
There is PL2303 USB UART Board mini shown in some YouTube videos but not sure if my cable will work or not.

Can you include more of the information from the links here in the question body? Specifically, the specific steps you followed setting this up. Also, what do you mean when you say "most yt videos show with the USB not this USB cable..."? Please EDIT your post to add this and other clarifying and expanding information. Do not reply down here in comments unless you have a question regarding one of the questions we have asked you.

@music2myear I edited it, hopefully I made it more clear now
